# Trailing return type issue when using restricted function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, c++-amp

I am writing a library using C++AMP for the internals, and I have discovered the following does not work and I am curious as to why (as it works if I remove `restrict(amp)` from the functor):

```
template <typename T>
using SumType = decltype( std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>() );

template <typename T, typename Func>
auto TestFunc(T t, Func f) -> SumType<decltype(f(t))>
{
    return f(t) + f(t);
}

int main() {
    auto f = []( float flVal ) restrict(amp) {
         return flVal * flVal;
    };

    float flResult = TestFunc( 1.0f, f ); // Error here: "no instance of function template 'TestFunc' matches the argument list"
}
```

However, if I remove the `restrict(amp)` from the definition of `f`, the program compiles as expected. Is there a clause in the AMP open-standard that can shed light on this?

---

Moreover, if we use the following in the definition of `TestFunc`, it compiles correctly even with the `restrict(amp)` specifier:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
auto TestFunc( T t, Func f ) -> T
{
    return f(t) + f(t);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add `restrict(amp)` to `TestFunc` (i.e `auto TestFunc(...) restrict(amp) -> ...`)

Comment: @0x499602D2 I get a compiler error informing me that no overload has the correct restrict specifiers.

Comment: Are those errors the full complete errors?

Comment: @0x499602D2 No; the first error (the no instance of ...) is in full: `error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type TestFunc(T,Func)'
1>          With the following template arguments:
1>          'T=float'
1>          'Func=main::<lambda_ba4858c186e1d28286129d3be2d36e18>'` And the second is: `error C3930: 'TestFunc' : no overloaded function has restriction specifiers that are compatible with the ambient context 'main'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is section 2.2 of the [AMP Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/E/40EA02D8-23A7-4BD2-AD3A-0BFFFB640F28/CppAMPLanguageAndProgrammingModel.pdf). You are getting the error "no instance of function template 'TestFunc' matches the argument list" because your code which calls `TestFunc` is not inside and restrict(amp) lambda (as part of a `parallel_for_each`. The compiler is therefore looking for a TestFunc with a `restrict(cpu)` decoration on it.

Does your code compile if you change your declaration as follows:

```
    auto f = [](float flVal) restrict(amp, cpu) {
        return flVal * flVal;
    };
```

Calling an amp restricted function/lambda outside the context of an AMP `parallel_for_each` is somewhat meaningless and will never work. Even if you can trick the compiler into not erroring.

Comment: Thanks Ade; I figured this out myself but forgot to put an answer to this question here myself so thanks for clarifying!!

Answer (score 0):

The [**restrict**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) keyword tells the compiler that there is only one pointer to that object.
This allows the compiler to do all kinds of optimizations.

But, your TestFunc is receiving the pointer function by value. So the compiler already knows you're trying to trick it by making a copy of that pointer.

To avoid making a copy, pass the parameter by reference:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
auto TestFunc(T t, Func& f) -> SumType<decltype(f(t))>
{
    return f(t) + f(t);
}
```

Comment: This is a different use of the `restrict` keyword unfortunately; it is a non-standard extension to MSVC which allows for compile-time checking of the validity of functions within a GPGPU context. Thank you for your answer anyway! :)